# Scoring "predictions" using Kullback-Leibler

Tags: bayesian, mathematical-statistics, information-theory, kullback-leibler

I'm interested in the following problem: I have a biased coin, which you measure, and make an estimate $p_{est}$ of the odds of getting a heads.  I then flip the coin a random (say, Poisson(10)) number of times, and observe $n_H$ heads and $n_T$ tails.  I'd like to "score" your prediction.

Current idea for a method: Use the prediction to set a Bayesian prior distribution on the real value of $p$.  Then use the data $(n_H, n_T)$ to obtain a posterior distribution.  Then use [Kullback-Leibler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence) to compare these distributions.  What I wanted was a method which takes account of $n:=n_H+n_T$ which is somehow the amount of *information* I'm gaining from my experiment.  If $n$ is small, then it seems reasonable to say that I learn less from the experiment, and so can assess your prediction less.

To give more details, I take a prior as $\operatorname{Beta}(tp_{est}, t(1-p_{est}))$ where $t>0$ somehow expresses my "confidence" in your prediction.  As this is a conjugate prior to the binomial, my posterior is $\operatorname{Beta}(tp_{est}+n_H, t(1-p_{est})+n_T)$.  I can then work out the Kullback-Leibler analytically, though it's rather messy.

Questions:

> Is this idea in the literature?
>
> There is an obvious dependence on $t$.  If $t$ is very large, then the prior completely dominates the data, and the KL divergence is small.  But what occurs for $t$ small seems complicated.  How do we choose $t$ appropriately?

(Asked on [Math.Stackoverflow](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2492229/scoring-predictions-using-kullback-leibler) but got no response.]